# Removing third dimension of photo

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, image-resizing

Is there a way to remove the third dimension from an image in MATLAB? I outputted an image from MATLAB and edited it in GIMP to remove white edges (which apparently added a third dimension). I would like this image to be just 512x512 instead of 512x512x3. This is the output when retrieving this size of the image.

```
size(eh2)

ans =

   512   512     3
```

Comment: simply 512x512 means a gray-scale scale. Are you sure you want to convert your image to a gray-scale image? `rgb2gray` is used for this purpose

Comment: Didn't realize that. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note: you can remove white edges the borders in MATLAB.

Comment: I tried doing that using the answers from a question on the MathWorks site, but they either removed the left/right side edges or none at all.

Comment: I'm not MatLab proficient, but most likely you're outputting an RGB image (no alpha) from GIMP. You can change the "mode" of the image to grayscale in "Image/Mode/Grayscale". That should save you the additional step of using 'rgb2gray'

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I assumed that since the input was a grayscale image that it would output that way as well.